# Command not triggering in view model which is bind to the contentview inside the accordion content in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on xamarin forms and i am facing issue in command. I have accordion items in the view. Inside the accordion item content i have a button. That button command not triggering. I bind the view model in run time to the particular item in the accordions. Please any help would be appreciated.

**I tried these below ways didn't work and button not get access the view model command.**
 1. BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference parentView},
    Path=BindingContext}" Command="{Binding ContinueCommand}".
 2. Command="{Binding BindingContext.ContinueCommand,
    Source={x:Reference parentView}}".

**In xaml code:**

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:Vm="clr-namespace:RCBazaar.ViewModels"
             x:Class="RCBazaar.Views.Templates.AddressTemplate"
             x:Name="parentView">
  <ContentView.Content>
        <StackLayout Padding="10">
            <Label HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Text="Mr.Akash Dayanand Central office house 1190,23th main,chamarajpete 6th block opposite to corner house Bangalore - 563738 Karnataka, India Tel:+91 9893393377"
                Style="{StaticResource lblNormal}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
            <Button Text="Continue" Command="{Binding BindingContext.ContinueCommand, Source={x:Reference parentView}}">                
            </Button>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

Comment: Please add the code for the actual commands

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gerald Versluis. I wanted to command trigger on click of button inside the accordion content. Actually view model binding at run time when accordion items are creating.

Comment: To help others answer your question, XAML and c# code would be helpful.

Comment: Did you forget to declare your commands as properties?

Comment: No its there in view model.